# Algebra Absolute Value

Tags: absolute-value

Let $a,b,c$, and $d$ be real numbers with $$|a-b|=2, \hspace{.2in} |b-c|=3, \hspace{.2in} |c-d|=4$$ What is the sum of all possible values of $|a-d|$? I am completely clueless on how to begin! It's due tomorrow and I need help.

Comment: Why did you wait until today?

Comment: Let's be constructive, @TBrendle.

Comment: Put $s either side of mathematics in future.

Answer (score 2):

There are eight cases.

1. $b>a$ or $b<a$
2. $c>b$ or $c<b$
3. $d>c$ or $d<c$

For all $2\times 2\times 2=8$ possibilities, work out $|a-d|$.  Since the problem is invariant under translation, you may as well assume $a$ is something simple, like $0$.

Here's one of the eight to get you started.  Suppose $b>a, c<b, d>c$.  We start with $a=0$.  Then $b=2$ since $b>a$.  Then $c=-1$ since $c<b$.  Lastly, $d=3$ since $d>c$.  Hence in this case $|a-d|=3$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   |a-b|=2 &\implies a-b = \pm 2\\
   |b-c|=3 &\implies b-c = \pm 3\\\
   |c-d|=4 &\implies c-d = \pm 4 \\
          &\implies a-d = 
   \begin{cases}
       2 + 3 + 4 &= 9 \\
       2 + 3 - 4 &= 1 \\
       2 - 3 + 4 &= 3 \\
       2 - 3 - 4 &= -5 \\
      -2 + 3 + 4 &= 5 \\
      -2 + 3 - 4 &= -3 \\
      -2 - 3 + 4 &= -1 \\
      -2 - 3 - 4 &= -9
   \end{cases}
\end{align}